# Resources/studies on physically describing emotion?

Tags: emotion, computational-modeling

I am wondering if there is an effort to described certain basic and perhaps more complicated emotions through the processes that occur in the brain. For example, when people get angry, certain stimulation occurs in brain... this might be really hard to measure.

I imagine there can be common observations between subjects but they won't be exact?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this meta-analysis](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004066)? Also [this one](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/behavioral-and-brain-sciences/article/div-classtitlethe-brain-basis-of-emotion-a-meta-analytic-reviewdiv/80F95F093305C76BA2C66BBA48D4BC8A).

Comment: What do you mean by "stimulation"? There are lots of different ways of imaging the brain.

Comment: thank you very much @mrt this is exactly what I'm looking for. By stimulation, I guess I mean neuronal activation.